# Why is HERE Places API not working on device but on localhost?

Tags: ionic4, here-api, ionic5

I am trying to implement a location search API from HERE places-api inside an Ionic5 app.
Everything works fine in localhost environment but search stops working on the device.

Question: Is there a special App-Code or -Key for the use of devices (also for testing via Android Studio)? And why is it working on localhost and not on the device by testing with android-studio?

I tried to change app-code & app-id into app-key and tried also Rest, JS and Rest-JS auth credentials but it is not working. I have no idea what to do next because there is no error at testing on the device, there is just no reaction to this API.

index.html

```
       <script
            src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
            type="text/javascript"
            charset="utf-8"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
            type="text/javascript"
            charset="utf-8"
        ></script>

        <script
            src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-places.js"
            type="text/javascript"
            charset="UTF-8"
        ></script>
```

Search service

```
 public async searchLocation(search): Promise<any> {
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            app_id: "my-id",
            app_code: "my-code",
        });

        var searchParams = {
            q: search,
            in: "-180,-90,180,90"
        };

        return this.startSearch(platform, searchParams);
    }

    public async startSearch(platform: any, searchParams: object): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var search = new H.places.Search(platform.getPlacesService());
            const self = this;
            search.request(
                searchParams,
                {},
                function onResult(data: any) {
                    self.Result = data.results.items;
                    resolve(self.Result);
                },
                function onError(error: any) {
                    console.log("HERE search error", error);
                    reject(error);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

**EDIT - Error log**

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js - Line 43427 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [timeout] http://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=--myID--&app_code=--myCode--&in=49.9949556%2C10.1767104%3Br%3D10000&size=100 request failed
    Error: [timeout] http://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=--myID--&app_code=--myCode--&in=479.9949556%2C10.1767104%3Br%3D10000&size=100 request failed
        at Object.Zc (eval at <anonymous> (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:56:36), <anonymous>:11:176)
        at b (eval at <anonymous> (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:56:36), <anonymous>:9:440)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js:56:36), <anonymous>:10:43)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js:3741:31)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js:73280:33)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js:3740:60)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js:3518:47)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js:3815:34)
        at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js:3804:48)
```

Comment: If you remote debug the Android build, do you see anything in the console?

Comment: Yes, i added the error to my question at EDIT.

Comment: It says the request failed - you may need to whitelist there HERE APIs in your Android app. I'm a bit rusty w/ Cordova, but I know Android locked things down to make you clearly spell out what remote resources you were loading. This was normally done in the CSP area. See if you can add the HERE URLs and that should clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:

Thanks @Raymond, i fixed the usecase with another way.
Instead of my API call of my question i changed it to URL request by httpClient.

```
public async searchLocation(search): Promise<any> {
        const BASE_NOMINATIM_URL = "nominatim.openstreetmap.org";
        const DEFAULT_VIEW_BOX = "-25.0000%2C70.0000%2C50.0000%2C40.0000";
        const url = `https://${BASE_NOMINATIM_URL}/search?format=json&q=${search}&${DEFAULT_VIEW_BOX}&bounded=1`;
       
        return this.http.get(url).subscribe((ans) => {
            console.log("data", ans);
        });
    }
```

I don't know why the way inside my question is not working. But the URL way works.